# Counting until a specific number and start again + backwards

Tags: c#, counting, repeat

The thing is, I want to be able to increase/decrease a variable (int) by pressing up and down arrow keys. But how do I manipulate the variable, so it goes from 3 to 1 and backwards from 1 to 3 again?

I'm using Visual C# express 2010 and it is a Windows Console application! Sorry for the trouble!

I'm desperately trying to get into C# and am struggling with such basic things. I'd be very grateful if someone could help me with this. I've got this far, this should become a menu on where the user can scroll through three options: 1- New Game // 2- Load Game and 3- Exit Game

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iMOP = 0;

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow){
            }
            else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow){
            }

                switch (iMOP)
                {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional: I'll try to refresh the menu with Console.Clear, though I'll have to figure the counting issue.
I've translated it into this now: AND IT WORKS NOW THANKS FOR THE INPUT, GUYS!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            int iMOP = 1;

            Console.WriteLine(" >>New Game");
            Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
            Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");

            while (iMOP != 5)
            {
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        iMOP--;
                    }
                    else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        iMOP++;
                    }
                }

                if (iMOP == 0)
                {
                    iMOP = 3;
                }
                else if (iMOP == 4)
                {
                    iMOP = 1;
                }

                switch (iMOP)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("   New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Exit Game");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("   New Game");
                        Console.WriteLine("   Load Game");
                        Console.WriteLine(" >>Exit Game");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean... if you're reacting to key presses, that will dictate whether you increase or decrease the variable. Maybe if you posted the code you've got so far and explained the difference between what it does and what you want it to do, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: So you want the number to "wrap"? The modulus operator (`%`) is your friend here. If you post what you have, it would be easier to help.

Comment: When your question involves any user interface or input (i.e. arrow keys initiating a process), you should list what platform you are working with because you will get different answers: WPF, Windows Forms, Web?

Comment: You need a loop in that code, perhaps console isn't the best choice here?

Comment: I think modulus might help me out a lot here. I'll try that!

Comment: What do you mean by twice? Your code looks correct (though you could replace the if statements with a modulus operation).

Comment: How do I utilize modulo in here? I can't see how, unfortunately.
(I was reading the key input twice it seemed.)

Comment: `iMop = (iMop % 3) + 1` will "loop" the numbers, put it in place of your if checks

Comment: Wow, I never thought of adding operators into variables. You have just opened eyes.

Comment: @FoX That is something you will do *all the time*. There are even special operators (`+=` and family) that shorten it for you! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To "loop" the numbers; replace:

```
if (iMOP == 0)
{
   iMOP = 3;
}
else if (iMOP == 4)
{
    iMOP = 1;
}
```

with:

```
iMOP = (iMOP % 3) + 1;
```

`%` returns the remainder after division; so it can only return 0, 1, or 2. Then you add 1 to get the range 1, 2, and 3. Note this trick is *exactly* the same as the one you use to scale a random double:

```
int scaledRandom = (rand.NextDouble() % max) + min;
```

Comment: Can you refer me to a tutorial which would help me, let's say, jump to another menu? I dont want to scramble everything into if statements or loops forever.

Comment: @FoX Theres not really a tutorial for that. In a console application; a nested menu system is a non-trivial design. I have  a good one in mind; but its a bit higher than introductory level C#. If you ask a new question about it; I'll try to help.